# Show count of changes on git side bar vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reasons the side bar does not show count on VS code when there is changes. How do I enable this?

Current:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Is it because your local main branch is up to date, i.e., there is no new commits to pull from origin? If that's the case, it will not show any numbers

Comment: no, not really. i checked :)